# What does it mean if all the coefficient estimates in a lasso regression converge to zero?

Tags: multiple-regression, matlab, regularization

I attempted to run lasso on a 12 X 52 matrix (11 predictors) using this MATLAB function http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/stats/lasso.html. I found that the results converged to zero.

How should I interpret this?

In the interests of full disclosure, I'd like to state that this isn't what happens when I include my full set of predictors. However, it does happen when I remove some of the predictors that (subjectively) seem to be the better ones from my data set before running lasso.

Comment: Why not take it at face value? Weak predictors are getting their coefficients shrunken away to nothing (for a given value of the shrinkage parameter).

Comment: Thanks. I knew that lasso tended to parsimonious models but didn't realise that in the circumstances I described it could set all the coefficients to zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will always happen for large-enough values of $\lambda$ (the regularization coefficient). (If your predictors aren't very good, this will be a very small value.) Are you providing it explicitly? The linked documentation says for the parameter `Lambda`:

> Vector of nonnegative `Lambda` values. See Definitions.
>
> – If you do not supply `Lambda`, `lasso` calculates the largest value of `Lambda` that gives a nonnull model. In this case, `LambdaRatio` gives the ratio of the smallest to the largest value of the sequence, and `NumLambda` gives the length of the vector.
>
> – If you supply `Lambda`, `lasso` ignores `LambdaRatio` and `NumLambda`.
>
> Default: Geometric sequence of `NumLambda` values, the largest just sufficient to produce `B = 0`

So, if you're passing an explicit value for `Lambda`, it's probably too large. Otherwise, you'd expect a sequence of results for different values of `Lambda`, only the largest of which would return all zeros. If that's not what you're getting, then can you post the exact function call and maybe your `X` and `Y` to further debug?

---

**Update:** Based on your comment, I see the problem: you're including the answer as a predictor! When I run your code, I get a `13 x 39` matrix `B`, where `B(1:end-1, :)` is all 0 and `B(end, :)` starts close to 1 and decreases as the regularization increases down to 0. This is just saying that the best fit is to take the answer, and scale it down a bit due to the regularization. :)

Instead, take the answer out of your predictors: `[B, FitInfo] = lasso(X(:, 1:end-1), y);` will work, and give you predictions that make more sense.

---

**Update again:** Okay, now that we've figured out you're not actually including the answer as a predictor, time to explain what's going on a little more. :)

The LASSO results depend on a regularization parameter, called $\lambda$. The thing that it minimizes is $ \tfrac{1}{2} \| X b - y \|_2^2 + \lambda \| b \|_1$, which is half the mean-squared error in the predictions with linear weightings $b$, plus the sum of the absolute values of the elements in $b$. In a Bayesian setting, you can think of this as a model where $y \approx \sum_i b_i x_i$ (with Gaussian noise), but with a ([Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution)) prior on the elements $b_i$ which results in many of them coming out as zero. The strength of that prior is set by $\lambda$. In other words, for high values of $\lambda$, LASSO will always give you a zero vector; for $\lambda \to 0$, as I mentioned before, it becomes the standard least squares fit.

Since you often don't have any reason to favor a particular value of $\lambda$, `lasso` gives you a few different ones by default. In particular, it gives you the smallest value of $\lambda$ such that $b = 0$, and then various smaller values of $\lambda$ backing off in a geometric series. These are stacked up into a matrix `B`, and for these default values of the parameters it gives you 39 different values of $\lambda$. So, `B(:, 1)` is a result fairly close to least-squares; `B(:, 2)` is a result a little closer to having some zeros, and so on, up to `B(:, end-1)` which will have only very few (in this case, one) nonzero elements, and then `B(:, end)` is always all zeroes.

Does that help?

Comment: I'm not passing an explicit value for lambda. I think the problem is that I hadn't realised that lasso might set all the predictors to zero if it didn't like any of them. I thought that this occurring was evidence in itself of a bug.

Comment: Your call is just `lambda(X, Y)`? I'm surprised, then; as $\lambda \to 0$, lasso becomes least-squares, which should (almost) never get an exact zero. Maybe Matlab has a seemingly-undocumented lower limit on $\lambda$, though. Could you post the data matrices?

Comment: Data matrix is at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53771404/example.csv. In MATLAB I just ran X = dlmread('example.csv'), y = X(:,13), and [B,FitInfo] = lasso(X,y). I've left in one 'good' predictor so it only seems to converge to zero on the 99th iteration. If you take out column 5 of the file it converges to zero pretty much straight away.

Comment: @user1205901 Sorry it took me a few days to get to this, but I figured it out; see my update in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I realise that I'd been expressing what I did somewhat inaccurately. In MATLAB I just actually X = dlmread('example.csv'), y = X(:,13), X(:,13) = [], and [B,FitInfo] = lasso(X,y). The third bit I accidentally omitted from account in the comment written above, but I'd actually been shopping out column 13 all along. I feel that I'd therefore avoided the problem you identified. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Oh, okay. In that case, the returned matrix seems reasonable to me. Remember that it's a matrix of different weights corresponding to different regularization values $\approx$ strength of the prior, so that the fact that the last column is all zero is expected (v. strong prior towards zero).

Comment: Thanks again - your answers have been extremely helpful. Are you able to expand a little on your last sentence? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: @user1205901 Okay, check my update in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that final update tied things together wonderfully well for me.